# ?: operator on sprintf

Tags: c++, printf, logical-operators

Apparently too much Python or too much of any dynamically typed language is not healthy for a programmer. Anyways, I'm struggling with a C++ exercise and have a quick question about syntax. I couldn't find any source code where this is applied (if possible).

Can I use a statement which includes the ?: operator as a sprintf argument?. This is my no-compling code so you get an idea:

```
return sprintf("The cosine of %2f %s is %2f", angle, (angleType == "g" ? "degrees" : "radians"), result);
```

***angleType*** is a value entered by the user specifying if he's entering degrees or radians.

***angle*** is the value for the angle.

***result*** is the actual cosine value.

I wanted to print a message as descriptive as possible so I came up with this.

If this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: is `angleType` char or string? `angleType == 'g'` makes more sense

Comment: angleType is std::string

Comment: Also, **NEVER USE `sprintf`!** Always use `snprintf` (or where that's not available, `_snprintf`). `sprintf` may well be the cause of more buffer overrun attack vectors than any other C-standard library function.

Comment: @Martin: How? He's not even using `sprintf` correctly. `sprintf` doesn't return a string; it prints to a buffer you specify, and he didn't specify a buffer.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, you can use `?:` anywhere an expression is expected.

One of your problems is probably with the condition, `angleType == "g"`. In C and C++, you cannot compare strings like that; you need to use `strcmp` or something like that. Unless `angleType` is a `std::string`, in which case this should just work.

The other problem is that you seem to be expecting `sprintf` to return a string. Instead, *you* are responsible for passing it a string, to which it will then write its output. But since this is C++, it's better to use `std::string` anyway!

If this doesn't solve your problem, post your compiler error message!

Comment: strcmp didn't work... but as you mentioned I'm using std::string, or at least I believe I do.
`#include <string.h>` and then `using namespace std;`. The variable is declared as `string angleType;`.

Comment: Here's compiler message, on line where I use `?:`
cannot convert ‘double’ to ‘const char*’ for argument ‘2’ to ‘int sprintf(char*, const char*, ...)’

Comment: Yep, that's related to the second problem I mentioned. You need to pass *two* string arguments: the output string, and the format string. Here, "string" means C-style string, i.e. pointer to an array of `char`s. Don't even *think* of using `sprintf` with a C++ string as its output. Better use `std::ostringstream` for this kind of formatting job.

Answer (score 4):

First problem, take another look at the prototype in `sprintf(3)`:

```
   int sprintf(char *str, const char *format, ...);
```

The first argument is a buffer that `sprintf(3)` writes into. You've given it the format string.

Second problem: `angleType == "g"` -- string comparisons in C don't work that way. `== 'g'` would work, if `angleType` is a `char`. Or if you're confident you've got a C++ `std::string`, sure, but this line alone doesn't have that data.

Comment: Right! I missed the first argument. Changed it to `char buffer[50]`, as the docs example.
Now it compiles, but with a warning:
`warning: deprecated conversion from string constant to ‘char*’`
On execution gives Segmentation Fault arriving to problematic line!

Comment: @horhay.romero Are you passing the char[50] now as the first or second argument? Leaving the constant string as the first argument would cause this warning and the runtime exception. If this is not the case, post some code for your follow-up question.

Comment: @horhay, I think the warning comes from C++ preferring `"strings"` to be `std::string` rather than C's `char *` (but I'm frequently out-of-touch with C++). Is the `char buffer[50]` an auto-allocated variable that goes out of scope with the `return ...` statement? You need to `malloc(3)` or `new` that buffer (or provide it from whatever function called _this_ function), so that it can be dereferenced after this function ends.

Comment: @eran is right. The conversion occurs when a string literal is passed as the first argument (which should have been the `char buffer[50]`). The segfault happens when trying to overwrite the `"The cosine of %2f %s is %2f"` string literal.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the problem with your code: `angleType == "g"`, if I guess right that angleType is a char*, not an std::string. Try changing it to `strcmp(angleType, "g") == 0` and see if it is correct.

I do not see any problem with ?:, its only constraint that both results must be the same type.